# Can `MagicMock` compare with int in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, mocking, magicmock

I am migrating python's version (2->3) of my project. The tests works fine for python2, but complains for python3, the error is like

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'MagicMock' and 'int'
```

here is a minimal case

```py
# test_mock.py
try:
    from mock import MagicMock
except:
    from unittest.mock import MagicMock

def test_mock_func():
    a = MagicMock()
    b = a.value

    if b > 100:
        assert True
    else:
        assert True
```

just run `py.test .`

These hacks not work

```
MagicMock.__le__ = some_le_method # just not working

MagicMock.__le__.__func__.__code = some_le_method.__func__.__code__ # wrapper_descriptor does not have attribute __func__
```

Comment: If that worked in Python 2 the comparison is faulty making the test faulty as well. Python 2 was less strict and comparison results were surprising sometimes. So, what are actually testing with that?

Comment: It's where the code handling web requests, the response has a field which should be a timestamp. To avoid network communication I send a `MagicMock` as the response. The error occurs where comparing the timestamp with another.

Comment: `a.value` is undefined unless explicitly set. You should set it (to a number), and then the comparison will be possible.

Comment: No, it's not undefined. It's an instance of `MagicMock`

Answer (score 1):

You should assign the `__gt__` inside `b` or `a.value`

```
# self is MagicMock itself
b.__gt__ = lambda self, compare: True
# or
a.value.__gt__ = lambda self, compare: True
```